# Didn't find class "android.window.OnBackInvokedCallback" and "android.graphics.ImageDecoder$OnHeaderDecodedListener"

Tags: flutter

```
WM-WrkMgrInitializer: Initializing WorkManager with default configuration.
 Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.flutter.embedding.android.d$a>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/window/OnBackInvokedCallback;
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance!() (Class.java:-2)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1078)
     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2563)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2732)
     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:103)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:912)
     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:802)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.window.OnBackInvokedCallback" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
     at java.lang.Object java.lang.Class.newInstance!() (Class.java:-2)
     at android.app.Activity android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String, android.content.Intent) (Instrumentation.java:1078)
     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2563)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2732)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:103)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:802)

ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer search path /data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/lib/arm:/data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a for namespace 0x9d414090
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.flutter.embedding.engine.d>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/graphics/ImageDecoder$OnHeaderDecodedListener;
    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI$c.a() (SourceFile:-1)
    at void b3.a$b.b() (SourceFile:-1)
    at b3.a b3.a$b.a() (SourceFile:-1)
    at b3.a b3.a.e() (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(android.content.Context, e3.d, io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI, io.flutter.plugin.platform.p, java.lang.String[], boolean, boolean) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(android.content.Context, java.lang.String[], boolean, boolean) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.android.e.G() (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.android.e.p(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.android.d.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6709)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2624)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2732)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:103)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:802)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.graphics.ImageDecoder$OnHeaderDecodedListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/lib/arm, /data/app/com.yjt.ad-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
     at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI$c.a() (SourceFile:-1)
    at void b3.a$b.b() (SourceFile:-1)
    at b3.a b3.a$b.a() (SourceFile:-1)
    at b3.a b3.a.e() (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(android.content.Context, e3.d, io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI, io.flutter.plugin.platform.p, java.lang.String[], boolean, boolean) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>(android.content.Context, java.lang.String[], boolean, boolean) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.android.e.G() (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.android.e.p(android.content.Context) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void io.flutter.embedding.android.d.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (SourceFile:-1)
    at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6709)
    at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2624)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2732)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1483)
    at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:103)
    at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
    at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6141)
    at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

It works fine in debug mode, but this problem occurs after packaging.

Comment: which package is producing this issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.